# How does iPhone resize images?

Tags: iphone

Does iPhone automatically use bicubic resizing, or bicubic sharpening?

Say I have an image that will be 100 X 100 in the iPhone. I know I should make it 200 X 200 and append @2x.png so iPhone 4 high resolution screens can use that version. Assuming file size makes no difference (a huge assumption, I know)... would it matter if I just use a 800 X 800 image and let the iPhone do the resizing itself? Rather than me manually resizing a 800 X 800 image to 200 X 200? What different would it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would consume unnecessary memory and processor cycles.

*Addition:* Perceived image quality is a subjective issue—why don't you try it and see? Be sure to test it on older devices. If you make an exact pixel double, or quadruple, or in the case of 800x800 down to 100x100 octouple version, the downsizing is more straightforward and that may help. Frankly, there are few developers who don't care about all three of disk space, memory, and processor cycles, all of which relate to UI performance and thus end user experience, and exporting images in the correct sizes is not that difficult a step in professional development, so you're not likely to get many more answers here as it isn't something most people would contemplate.

Comment: yes, I know. Ok. Assume file size, memory and processor cycles are not an issue. i'm talking about image quality, that's the crux of my question. will image quality suffer